# Adjusting Timezone - Convert XML DateTime to SQL DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, xml

We are using TypedDataSet in our application. Data is passed to procedure in form of XML for insert/update.

Now after populating DE with data, datetime remains the same though timezone information is added as below.

Date in DB: 2009-10-29 18:52:53.43
Date in XML: 2009-10-29T18:52:53.43-05:00

Now when I am trying to convert below XML to SQL DateTime it is adjusting 5 hours and I am getting

2009-10-29 23:52:53.430
as the final output, which is wrong. Need to find a way to extract datetime from below XML snippet ignoring timezone.

I have XML in following format, with timezone difference -05.00

```
<Order>
   <EnteredDateTime>2009-10-29T18:52:53.43-05:00</EnteredDateTime>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert into typed xsd date time and then use the value method to convert that value to a sql datetime.

```
select convert(xml, '<DateTimeWithTimeZone>2012-09-15T16:08:14.787-05:00</DateTimeWithTimeZone>').value('xs:dateTime(/DateTimeWithTimeZone[1])', 'datetime')
```

[Convert datetime with time zone to SQL datetime](http://www.mytinytips.com/2012/08/convert-datetime-with-time-zone-to-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

2009-10-29 18:52:53.43 is not the same time as 2009-10-29T18:52:53.43-05:00.  It's the first step that is incorrect.  The conversion from XML to SQL DateTime is correct.

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Ok. I understand that. But then what's the solution? Do I need to make change to my select statement? Why "2009-10-29 18:52:53.43" is getting converted to "2009-10-29T18:52:53.43-05:00"?

Comment: I've never seen SQL Server output a date in that format.  Where is the DB->XML string happening?  That's where the issue is.  Do you have control over this code?

Comment: I don't. We are using Enterprise Library to populate this dataset.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for simply forwarding with an external link, but i found this resource useful recently and always favour authoritative info.

[Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx)